# How to store last processed file of S3 to Redshift database

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

For now i have copied Data from Amazon S3 to Amazon Redshift Using AWS Data Pipeline only for current date and time. I want to copy data from S3 to Redshift for every 30 minutes. And also the last processed S3 file name is stored into another Redshift table.

Could  somebody answer this question ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`RedshiftCopyActivity` data pipeline object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-redshiftcopyactivity.html) to do exactly this. The `schedule` field in the `RedshiftCopyActivity` object accepts a [data pipeline schedule object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-schedule.html) that can run on 30 minute intervals. You'll need to define a [full pipeline in JSON](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-redshift-define-pipeline-cli.html) including all your AWS resource info (Redshift data nodes, EC2 instances, S3 bucket & key). The filepath for the source data file in the JSON template could point to a static file which is overwritten every 30 minutes by whatever produces the data.